# What is delta in the maximization step in this EM algorithm?

Tags: naive-bayes, expectation-maximization

[image: EM Algorithm]

The algorithm is used to classify english vs non-english tweets from unlabeled data. Given n observed tweets (x1 ... xn) where each tweet xi is a collection of d words (xi1 ... xid). y is the class (english/non-english). We use EM to estimate the parameters (thetas). It is used in this paper:
http://www2013.wwwconference.org/companion/p593.pdf

Comment: I quickly checked the paper and could not find the definition of $\delta$. I believe this symbol is not specific to EM algorithm, so it would be helpful to contact the authors directly.